# int* value not holding any value

Tags: c, variables, integer

I'm trying to pass and store many values of many ints however, the values I need aren't holding the appropriate value

The problem code is below, the values that aren't holding a value that should be are: int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int a1, int b1, int c1, int d1, int e1, int a1lock, int b1lock, int c1lock, int d1lock, int e1lock

```
void stringVowelBreakdown(char xString[30], char yString[30], int length, int* a, int* b, int* c, int* d, int* e, int* a1, int* b1, int* c1, int* d1, int* e1, int* a1lock, int* b1lock, int* c1lock, int* d1lock, int* e1lock)
{
    int i = 0;
    int ptr = 0;

    while (i <= length)
    {
        char seperateChar = xString[i];

        switch (seperateChar)
        {
        case 65://A
            yString[ptr] = seperateChar;
            ptr++;
            a++;
            if (a1 == 0 && a1lock == 0)
            {
                *a1 = i;
                *a1lock = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 97://a
            yString[ptr] = seperateChar;
            ptr++;
            a++;
            if (a1 == 0 && a1lock == 0)
            {
                *a1 = i;
                *a1lock = 1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Here's the main if you need it:

```
int main()
{
    char stringOne[30] = "\0";
    char stringTwo[30] = "\0";
    int stringOneLength = 0;

    int acount = 0;

    int aFirstIndex = 0;

    int alock = 0;
    int elock = 0;
    int ilock = 0;
    int olock = 0;
    int ulock = 0;

    enterString(&stringOne[0]);

    stringOneLength = (stringLengthFinder(&stringOne[0], stringOneLength));

    stringVowelBreakdown(&stringOne[0], &stringTwo[0], stringOneLength, &acount, &aFirstIndex, &alock);

    return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to output the following:

Enter a word/sentence no longer than 30 characters - anything after the 30th character will be lost
yikes
Length of xString is 5
The original string is: yikes
The second string is: ie
'A' appears 0 time(s)
'E' appears 1 time(s)
'I' appears 1 time(s)
'O' appears 0 time(s)
'U' appears 0 time(s)
'A' doesn't appear
'E' first appears in index 3
'I' first appears in index 1
'O' doesn't appear
'U' doesn't appear

However, it only outputs this:

Enter a word/sentence no longer than 30 characters - anything after the 30th character will be lost
yikes
Length of xString is 5
The original string is: yikes
The second string is: ie
'A' appears 0 time(s)
'E' appears 0 time(s)
'I' appears 0 time(s)
'O' appears 0 time(s)
'U' appears 0 time(s)
'A' doesn't appear
'E' doesn't appear
'I' doesn't appear
'O' doesn't appear
'U' doesn't appear

Any and all help would be appreciated - If you need anything else from me please comment below

Edit: Removed parts of code as they were repeats of the 'A' and 'a' segments

Comment: `case 65://A` --> `case 'A':`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] along with a description of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: `a++;` --> `(*a)++;`

Comment: One suggestion, instead of  passing so many parameters create a struct with members of each and just pass the address of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You're not distinguising between the pointer variable and value it points to. That are two separate entities.

Let's take a look at the `a` variable. It is defined as `int *a`, so it is a pointer.
That means that `a++` increments the pointer and thus changes what it points to. To increment the value pointed to `(*a)++` is required. This will increment the integer that `a` points to.

Likewise in the case of `int *a1` there is this (abbreviated):

```
if (a1 == 0) {
     *a1 = i
}
```

Which makes no sense as this says if `a1` points to nowhere, set its value to `i`. This is sure way to crash your program.

What you actually want (I guess) is:

```
if ( *a1 == 0) {
    *a1 = i;
}
```

Which sets the value of the integer pointed to by `a1` in case it happened to be zero.